# how can i sync permission for specific database

Tags: laravel

i can not able to sync permission
i have multiple database
it alwayes get database in config->database.php first database
how can i sync permission using database name

```
            $roles_data = array('name' => $request->role);
            Role::on($request->project)->where('id', $request->role_id)->update($roles_data);
            $role = Role::on($request->project)->find($request->role_id);            
            $role->syncPermissions($request->permissions);
```

Comment: We don't have clear picture about what do you really want. Show as some context about your idea. (e.g) just parent to child or child to parent also.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.